# Converting/typecasting go interface object to concrete type

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In the implementation of `informer`, one can provide event handlers like below.

```
podInformer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs {
   // When a new pod gets created
   AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
       k8s.handleAddPod(obj)
   },
   // When a pod gets updated
   UpdateFunc: func(oldObj interface{}, newObj interface{}) {
       k8s.handleUpdatePod(oldObj, newObj)
   },
   // When a pod gets deleted
   DeleteFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
       k8s.handleDeletePod(obj)
   },
})
```

This is an example event handler for processing the `Pod` related events. So far, I have written the handler as below; however, it is failing to read the object.

I am not able to typecast the `obj interface{}` into `v1.Pod` and an attempt to read it failing. The value of flag `ok` is coming out `false`. Can someone please suggest whats missing in this code?

```
func (k8s *K8S) handleAddPod(obj interface{}) {
    pod, ok := obj.(v1.Pod)
    if ok {
        log.Debug("Status: " + string(pod.Status.Phase))
        log.Debug("Pod added: " + pod.Name + " " + pod.DeletionTimestamp.String())
    }
}
```

Comment: To debug, fmt.Printf(“obj: %T”, obj) to find the actual concrete type. The question uses  a type assertion, not a conversion or s typecast.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am relatively new to go and learning it on the job. I tried printing the %T, and I see this (2019-08-11T22:58:19-07:00 DBG k8s.go:1530: obj: *v1.Pod).

Comment: The output shows it's a pointer, so do `obj.(*v1.Pod)`, and not `obj.(v1.Pod)`.

Comment: `obj: *v1.Pod` implies that the type of `obj` is `*v1.Pod` — *pointer to* `v1.Pod`. Your type-test uses `v1.Pod` rather than `*v1.Pod`.

Answer (score 0):

I could read the values and the content of the `obj` using this code.

```
func (k8s *K8S) handleAddPod(obj interface{}) {
    pod, ok := obj.(*v1.Pod)   // Added * here.  
    if ok {
        log.Debug("Status: " + string(pod.Status.Phase))
        log.Debug("Pod added: " + pod.Name + " " + pod.DeletionTimestamp.String())
    }
}
```